# Why it says "Cannot create an instance of class com.app.myapp.viewModel" in android jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am new in adroid , so I have a simple project, I want to create simple register project, so I have viewmodel in my project and I amusing Hilt library also in there, and when I build project it is throw an error for

```
 myViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[MyViewModel::class.java]
```

as a "Cannot create an instance of class com.app.myapp.viewModel", I do not know what I missed?

```
  class Register : ComponentActivity() {

    private lateinit var  myViewModel: MyViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        
       
        myViewModel = [ViewModelProvider(this)::class.java]

        setContent {
            RegisterScreen(myViewModel)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun RegisterScreen(
    myViewModel: MyViewModel
  ) {

}
```

Comment: View model is required to be without custom constructor parameters(supported parameter is for example `SavedStateHandle`). If this doesn't help, add source code of your view model

Comment: I am not understand what you mean, but I am still do not get it how can ı use viewmodel in jetpack compose, I am not able to init it in activity

Comment: "add source code of your view model"

Comment: @PylypDukhov, I update

Comment: You're using Hilt in your view model, but I don't see the annotation on your activity. Follow hilt integration [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack#viewmodels)

Comment: @PylypDukhov, I am still not undsrtand how I will solve it

Comment: What have you tried after reading documentation? https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack#viewmodels

Comment: I add @AndroidEntryPoint above Register class

Comment: You also need `HiltAndroidApp` for your `Application` class, create it if you don't have it. Then make sure you have `kapt` configured according to documentation too.

Comment: @PylypDukhov, I understand tnx so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reasons may cause system can not create viewModel:

- Your viewModel class is not Public
- Your package name which contains viewModel contains special keywords (such a "package.new.feature")
- If you are using dagger hilt you should putt annotation `@HiltViewModel` above the class declaration and create constructor like

  ```
  @HiltViewModel
  class viewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel()
  ```
- With the dagger hilt You should use `hiltViewModel()` function to create instance for compose instead of `viewModel()`

dependency: `androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose`

```
   @Composable
   fun MyExample (viewModel: MyViewModel = hiltViewModel())
```

- Your ViewModel class does not extend from `androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel`

Comment: I get it, tnx so much :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a view model from the base class `ViewModel`. it doesn't work like this

You need to create your own viewmodel class and extend it from the base class `ViewModel` like this

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    
}
```

So your code will be like

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    // your implementation
}

class Register : ComponentActivity() {

private lateinit var  viewModel: MyViewModel // changes to this line

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
   
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[MyViewModel::class.java] // changes to this line

    setContent {
        RegisterScreen(viewModel)
    }
}
```

}

**BUT** if you are using compose you should look at the [integration](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#viewmodel) between viewmodel and compose

to make your composable use the viewModel without you creating it then passing it to the composable

```
@Composable
fun MyExample(
    viewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()
) {
    // use viewModel here
}
```

Comment: I update question   can you check again pls

Comment: how can I use it in compose, I am using compose, can u update ur answer if possbile

Comment: Could you please explain, what you want to know how to use it

Answer (score -1):

You should create your `ViewModel` class extending from the `ViewModel`, something like `RegisterViewModel`.

Take a look at the documentation for more info:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Comment: I update question   can you check again pls